# csrfmiddlewaretoken included in the search url query

Tags: python, django

The problem is I have 2 searches, one is a search for job seekers to find jobs and another is a search for companies to find job seekers. The expected result is to have `http://localhost:8000/search-job-seeker/?&q=searchquery` but what I'm getting is `http://localhost:8000/search-job-seeker/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=pF6HWEH2rOTvZTRsXzaDuQ9GiGw9ChmukeCYUSND15gzFPCKWmRtRGvVecMHIWKK&q=searchquery` I don't see any error messages when I debug in the console or in the terminal.

I've tried to use `get` in the form which results in the `http://localhost:8000/search-job-seeker/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=pF6HWEH2rOTvZTRsXzaDuQ9GiGw9ChmukeCYUSND15gzFPCKWmRtRGvVecMHIWKK&q=searchquery` but when I use `post` method in the form, I get `http://localhost:8000/search-job-seeker/` and the search result comes out with out the `q=searchquery` in the url.

My view for this is:

```py
class JobSeekerSearchView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = "core/job_seeker_search.html"
    form_class = JobSeekerSearchForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handle HTTP POST requests, process form data, search for job seekers, and render the template.
        
        Args:
            self: the instance of the class
            request: the HTTP request object
            *args: variable length argument list
            **kwargs: variable length keyword argument list
            
        Returns:
            HTTP response object
        """
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        job_seeker_results = []

        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data["q"]

            # Search for job seekers using PostgreSQL full-text search and icontains
            job_seeker_results = Seeker.objects.annotate(
                search=SearchVector("seekerprofile__pk", "seekerprofile__headline"),
            ).filter(
                Q(search=SearchQuery(query))
                | Q(seekerprofile__skills__icontains=query)
                | Q(seekerprofile__rate__icontains=query)
            )

        context = {"query": query, "job_seeker_results": job_seeker_results, "form": form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

The template form is:

```
        <form class="d-flex" method="get" action="{% url 'core:seeker_search' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search job seekers..." value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
```

Here is the `forms.py`

```py
class JobSeekerSearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
```

Comment: will you post the `forms.py`?. does it contains field `q`

Comment: @SuhailPIXL posted the forms.py

Comment: i think you don't need forms for searching. forms are used for validations and saving to database. i updated the views in my answer

Comment: If the form method is GET, it will send the data as query parameters. If it is POST, then data will be sent as the HTTP body. Hence you see the csrf token in query for GET and not in POST.

Comment: You just need to remove `{% csrf_token %}` from your form... GET requests don't need any CSRF Token.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Removing the `{% csrf_token %}` fixed the issue. Now I learned that you don't need a `{% csrf_token %}` when performing a get request.

Comment: Note: A GET request doesn't need a CSRF Token but you should be careful to make sure that a GET request doesn't produce any side effects otherwise you'd still end up being vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat will take note of that side effects